# How can you easily visualize debugging data generated by a C application?

Tags: c, debugging, artificial-intelligence, dashboard, reinforcement-learning

I am developing an artificial neural net for reinforcement learning in CUDA C. However, I haven't found an efficient way of debugging. I would like to have a customizable dashboard. For example, I would like to see how the exploration rate is developing or the current performance of the agent. Currently, I print out information on the command line. But obviously, this is quite messy.

An idea was to send data via HTTP to a server which then visualizes it on an HTML site. However, this would require a large effort. Are there existing solutions to this problem?

Comment: In your first case it is easier to redirect output to a text file and explore it in a text editor. With MSVC I can use `printf` for `stdout` messages which can be redirected, and `cprintf` for messages which always go to the console.

Comment: What sort of visualization is this - is it just a graph that changes or some fancy graphics that reorganizes trees?

Comment: I don't necessarily need fancy graphics. But I would like to customize the output. Primarily, I want to show variable values and how they change over time. But, in the future, I would like to add CPU usage, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for visualizing a neural network is as a graph. Lucky for you there is a great tool out there called graphviz (which is also quite handy for visualizing code and call graphs).
http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Here is an article describing how to visualize the neural net. You need to figure out how you can use this to show the evolution of your network.

http://zhu45.org/posts/2017/May/25/draw-a-neural-network-through-graphviz/

Comment: This might be part of the solution. But primarily I want to show variable values. This tool can only show the ANN architecture.